# The MAP_FIXED constant of mmap sys_call

Tags: c, constants, mmap, system-calls

What does the constant MAP_FIXED do for mmap?

I've read it in the manual but still don't understand its purpose and for which cases it's good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MAP_FIXED specifies that the mmap'd memory should be at the virtual address passed as the first argument to `mmap()`.  This has very limited usage in modern user programs and in fact some operating systems simply return an error if MAP_FIXED is specified.

One possible use for MAP_FIXED is when implementing a memory allocator (such as malloc()), mmap() may be used to carve out the heap memory.